# Drag-and-drop React UI builder?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-bootstrap, chakra-ui

I want to build my own web-based version of MS Paint using React. I have the basic javascript canvas code written and now I want to make a nice gui with a menu bar across the top, and a section on the left to select which tool to use, etc.

Can anyone recommend a drag-and-drop software with pre-made components like button, menu bar etc, to make it easy for me to make a professional-looking user interface? Alternatively, some tips on what my workflow should be like would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

A few projects listed on Reddit

[webiny-js](https://github.com/webiny/webiny-js)

[blocks-ui](https://blocks-ui.com/)

[openchakra.app](https://openchakra.app/)

[pagedraw.io](https://pagedraw.io/)

[craft.js](https://craft.js.org/)

Using webiny myself at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use [BulderX](https://builderx.io) It will give you the option to create UI by drag and drop and it will generate the code automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [loopple.com](https://www.loopple.com/react), currently working with Chakra UI.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).